# Sum xml comma values in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following problem. I want to sum all the xml comma values.

```
<Root>
 <Haus>
  <Teile>
    <Position Nummer="1">
        <Benennung>Das Haus 1</Benennung>
        <Gesamtpreis>27.65</Gesamtpreis>
        <Basispreis>24.04</Basispreis>
    </Position>
    <Position Nummer="2">
        <Benennung>Das Haus 2</Benennung>
        <Gesamtpreis>27.65</Gesamtpreis>
        <Basispreis>24.04</Basispreis>
    </Position>
    <Position Nummer="3">
        <Benennung>Das Haus 3</Benennung>
        <Gesamtpreis>133.29</Gesamtpreis>
        <Basispreis>115.9</Basispreis>
    </Position>
  </Teile>
  <Schutt>
    <Position Nummer="1">
        <Benennung>Das Haus 1</Benennung>
        <Gesamtpreis>27.65</Gesamtpreis>
        <Basispreis>24.04</Basispreis>
    </Position>
    <Position Nummer="2">
        <Benennung>Das Haus 2</Benennung>
        <Gesamtpreis>27.65</Gesamtpreis>
        <Basispreis>24.04</Basispreis>
    </Position>
    <Position Nummer="3">
        <Benennung>Das Haus 3</Benennung>
        <Gesamtpreis>133.29</Gesamtpreis>
        <Basispreis>115.9</Basispreis>
    </Position>
  </Schutt>
 </Haus>
</Root>
```

Now i want to sum in xsl all the values out of `Gesamtpreis` of `Teile` only.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/Haus/Teile/Position[Basispreis != Gesamtpreis or (Listenpreis*Anzahl)!= Gesamtpreis]">
    ???
</xsl:for-each>
```

I know i need to `format-number(Gesamtpreis, '#.##0,00', 'european')` for displaying the one comma value. But how can i sum all the values and get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check following Code:-

<xsl:template match="Root">
<xsl:variable name="ajeet_1" select="sum(//Teile/Position/Gesamtpreis)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($ajeet_1, '#.##0,00', 'euro')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
check following Code:-

<xsl:template match="Root">
<xsl:variable name="ajeet_1" select="sum(//Teile/Position/Gesamtpreis)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($ajeet_1, '#.##0,00', 'euro')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This works for ALL 'Gesamtpreis'. I updates the question. I need it only for 'Teile'.

Comment: <xsl:variable name="ajeet_1" select="sum(//Teile/Position/Gesamtpreis)"/>

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
Check difference between 'Gesamtpreis' and 'Basispreis':-

<xsl:template match="Root">
<xsl:variable name="ajeet_1" select="sum(//Teile/Position/Gesamtpreis)"/>
<xsl:variable name="ajeet_2" select="sum(//Teile/Position/Basispreis)"/>
<xsl:variable name="ajeet_3" select="$ajeet_1 - $ajeet_2"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($ajeet_3, '#.##0,00', 'euro')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You are the best.